# AVAudioUnitComponentManager won't instantiate

Tags: osx-yosemite, audiounit

When I add this line of code (to an empty new OS X 10.10 project):

```
AVAudioUnitComponentManager *manager = [AVAudioUnitComponentManager
sharedAudioUnitComponentManager];
```

I get this exception:

> Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property
>   on (NSWindow): -[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {0,
>   18446744073709551615} out of bounds; string length 3

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to give more context to your code, in case the problem is caused by something your program did before.  (I'm not familiar with OS X APIs so I don't know if the context is required, but it's generally a good idea.)

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey good idea, though this is in "viewDidLoad" of an new empty project.

Comment: if I add it to "viewDidAppear" I get this exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {0, 18446744073709551615} out of bounds; string length 3'